# Change single color in Altair plot

Tags: python, pandas, altair

Is there a way to change the color of just a single group in Altair plot, while leaving the rest the same? I like the default color scheme fine, but there is one group I want to change the color for.

For example, in a scatter-plot like this:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

iris = data.iris()

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalWidth',
    y='petalLength',
    color=alt.Color('species')
)
```

[image: example_scatterplot]

I would like to change the color of 'versicolor' to black, without changing the rest.

I know from the documentation that you can specify your own color scheme, or assign colors to each one of the groups, like so:

```
domain = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']
range_ = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalWidth',
    y='petalLength',
    color=alt.Color('species', scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=range_))
)
```

[image: example_scatterplot_2]

But I cannot find a simple way to change the color for a single species without affecting the rest of the colors.

Comment: If you want to change the green to black, the following correspondence is possible, is this what you are after? `range_ = ['red', 'black', 'blue']`

Comment: Not quite. I want to change the green to black while leaving the other colors *exactly* the same as they are in the original. I realize one solution would be to find the names of those exact tones and then change list as you suggest, but I was hoping for an approach that avoids doing that manually, as the real DataFrame I'm working with has quite a lot of groups.

Comment: For example, is it your intention to create a graph with the specified colors, convert the graph object to dictionary format, rewrite the colors from the resulting dictionary, and then convert the dictionary back to the graph object? `chart=alt.Chart(...);graph=chart.to_dict();graph['encoding']['color']['scale']['range'][1]='black';alt.Chart.from_dict(graph)`

Comment: That still requires for 'scale' and 'range' to have been defined beforehand. A dictionary made out of the chart object in the first example doesn't have those entries.

Comment: Was the answer you accepted the intent of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with an `alt.condition`, although the updated color will not appear in the legend:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

iris = data.iris()

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalWidth',
    y='petalLength',
    color=alt.condition("datum.species == 'setosa'", alt.value('yellow'), alt.Color('species'))
)
```

[image]

If you want to change the color *and* have it reflected in the legend, the only way to do so is to use a custom scale as you did in your question.

Comment: Would it be possible to separately change the color appearing in the legend to the same color? In any case, this is a good enough solution for me for now. Thank you!

Comment: The legend always reflects the color of the scale, so the way to change the color in the legend is to change the color in the scale in the manner you demonstrate in your question.